# Jboss eap 7 import vault configuration

Tags: jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I am new to Jboss, trying to migrate vault configuration from eap 6 to eap 7
copied vault folder from eap6 root to eap7 root

getting following error when i put vault configuration

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0230: Vault is not initialized; resolution of value expression is not possible.
```

following is my snippet of my configuration in standalone.xml

```
<system-properties>
..
<property name="ldap.bind.password" value="${VAULT::ldap::password::1}"
..
</system-properties>

<vault>
<vault-option name = "KEYSTORE_URL" value=${jboss.home.dir}/vault/vault.keystore"/>
<vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value = "XXXXX"/>
<vault-option name="SALT" value ="XXX"/>
<vault-option name="ITERATION-COUNT" value="44"/>
<vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="${jboss.home.dir}/vault"/>
</valut>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is Bug(https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-13842) has been raised  to avoid this ERROR message in the logs.. Please note that as a possible workaround the use of javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword property may be avoided altogether if the purpose is to only read from the trustStore rather than write to/modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is a bug raised for this issue: [EAP 7.06+ Bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-13842)
However, you can check if the vault expression is resolving to the correct value by using the following CLI command:

```
/core-service=platform-mbean/type=runtime:read-attribute(name=system-properties)
```